# I am having a problem with setContentView() method in android

Tags: android, setcontentview

Whenever I create a new activity there  is an error with name like for eg. `setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_image);`

and i am getting this [image: error mesage]

Comment: I always get this error. You can invalidate cache on "File" menu.
I run the app even with this error, It goes away after the app builds

Answer (score 0):

invalidate cache from file section of android studio, clean and build app.
this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Follow these three steps:

1. Android Studio > Build > Clean Project
2. Android Studio > Build > Rebuild Project
3. Android Studio > File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart

If still you face this problem then do `Sync Project with Gradle File` by pressing the following button. Hope this will work now.

[image: Sync Project with Gradle button]